# how to get real direction steps using Flutter? (draw real route)

Tags: google-maps, flutter, google-maps-api-3, dart

I'm working with taxi app. Is it possible to draw real route on real road using flutter?

I used this way: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#ExampleRequests

```
  getDirectionSteps(double destinationLat, double destinationLng) {
    network
        .get("origin=" +
            location.latitude.toString() +
            "," +
            location.longitude.toString() +
            "&destination=" +
            destinationLat.toString() +
            "," +
            destinationLng.toString() +
            "&key=api_key")
        .then((dynamic res) {
      List<Steps> rr = res;
      print(res.toString());

      ccc = new List();
      for (final i in rr) {
        ccc.add(i.startLocation);
        ccc.add(i.endLocation);
      }

      mapView.onMapReady.listen((_) {
        mapView.setMarkers(getMarker(location.latitude,location.longitude,destinationLat,destinationLng));
        mapView.addPolyline(new Polyline("12", ccc, width: 15.0));
      });
      _screenListener.dismissLoader();
      showMap();
    }).catchError((Exception error) => _screenListener.dismissLoader());
  }
```

my output look like this:

[image]

But I need like this: (draw destination route on real road)

[image]

Comment: I am finding it hard to understand what the actual problem is. Please can you elaborate it a bit.

Comment: @SahdeepSingh I updated my question. please check.. I added another photo..please check

Answer (score 9, accepted):

to find the exact route you have to get `points` out of the `polylineoverview` from the json from directions api.

This is how I extracted the exact route just like you show in the second image.

Its is a function that return points as a string

```
Future<String> getRouteCoordinates(LatLng l1, LatLng l2) async {
    String url =
        "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=${l1.latitude},${l1.longitude}&destination=${l2.latitude},${l2.longitude}&key=${Constants.anotherApiKey}";
    http.Response response = await http.get(url);
    Map values = jsonDecode(response.body);
    ProjectLog.logIt(TAG, "Predictions", values.toString());
    return values["routes"][0]["overview_polyline"]["points"];
  }
```

you will get a string of `points` somewhat similiar to this

```
 u|umDs`gwML}A_GGgFGAWwDEm@TcFGsAAa@BeA\QDe@AYISOKHKJGFw@^?jAAnAEnOA|GAhHEx@?jA@tC?XFLLf@Bf@@t@?xAA|E?dEEj_@GxMChG@tCIvl@@tAK`DQlA?zBApE?lBExNAlH@rMAtGJdDJnATfB`AnEdAzEj@~B|@lEF\xAvGnAlF~@lEv@`DvAxFxAxGzCdN`H`ZnEnRr@hDnB|IhDlNvKnd@vDhPrFzUzGjYxBtH|@hCdAzBXl@fAhBtAtBjBhCfArAdAhAvBtBlB|AjGfFhLzJfEzDzCvDz@pA`BpC`ApBbAzBxCrIr@rBjNta@x@nBbAlBzCbI|R|j@hA`FBVC`ASpD?lA[FiMpCaBVgABiAPoE~@cIdBiLfCcHdBsCl@yJvBmDt@y@l@{@X_@P[VGJGZCd@r@tCf@rBTbAV`BB`@?n@GdA@XHj@bAxBl@hBPjADf@?v@Ej@Ml@Ut@[r@]h@sA`C{@lAMZGl@KjECbDGhBuGMsJKcCGw@CqJCiECAd@ALoBbKs@jDM^x@j@vPfLvCnB~DnCx@f@R@RAd@GDIbBmDv@y@LId@On@A~EJX@pDJrADb@QFC
```

Now you will add the polyline in the set of polylines like this

```
_polyLines.add(Polyline(
        polylineId: PolylineId(Constants.currentRoutePolylineId),//pass any string here
        width: 3,
        geodesic: true,
        points: Utils.convertToLatLng(Utils.decodePoly(encodedPoly)),
        color: ConstantColors.PrimaryColor));
```

here `encodedPoly` is the same string that extracted from previous method.

In the function above you have to convert the `points\encodedPoly` into the list of latlng. Like i did using utils function.

Both functions that i used are

decodePoly :

```
// !DECODE POLY
  static List decodePoly(String poly) {
    var list = poly.codeUnits;
    var lList = new List();
    int index = 0;
    int len = poly.length;
    int c = 0;
    // repeating until all attributes are decoded
    do {
      var shift = 0;
      int result = 0;

      // for decoding value of one attribute
      do {
        c = list[index] - 63;
        result |= (c & 0x1F) << (shift * 5);
        index++;
        shift++;
      } while (c >= 32);
      /* if value is negative then bitwise not the value */
      if (result & 1 == 1) {
        result = ~result;
      }
      var result1 = (result >> 1) * 0.00001;
      lList.add(result1);
    } while (index < len);

    /*adding to previous value as done in encoding */
    for (var i = 2; i < lList.length; i++) lList[i] += lList[i - 2];

    print(lList.toString());

    return lList;
  }
```

and convertToLatLng() :

```
static List<LatLng> convertToLatLng(List points) {
    List<LatLng> result = <LatLng>[];
    for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
      if (i % 2 != 0) {
        result.add(LatLng(points[i - 1], points[i]));
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
```

This would make a exact route like i did in my app :

Here is the screenshot :
[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: if i want to get location list for encoded polyline, how can I get it using above code?

Comment: @gsm You need to convert encoded polyline to list of Points and from points you can get a list of LatLng. Both methods to get these (first points and then list of latlng) are there in the answer.

Comment: @SahdeepSingh hello, I want to change my polyline when user takes wrong turn , just like google map app is doing. Can you help?

Comment: @ShriyaPandya you might want to manage your state of origin and destination. and using live location you can make changes to origin variable and rerun the whole process of fetching the Route, after clearing the previous polyline.

Comment: @SahdeepSingh yes i am doing the same. while updating user live location , first clear the polyline list and then update live location latllng to source latlng. But this way the polyline blinks on map every single second. When i walk through the road, polyline stops showing. because that time live location changes frequently fast.

Comment: @ShriyaPandya the blink you are mentioning is bcoz you are removing polylines first and then making request to get route. You might want to first create new polyline and then update. Also yes, live tracking is very much frequent, you can add ~3 seconds gap in network request.

Comment: @SahdeepSingh i appreciate for your explanations. I am having some issue , provided my code below. Please check it. I am stuck here since 2 weeks.

Comment: @SahdeepSingh Your Answer is working fine for when the distance between origin and destination is low but when the destination is very far It's giving inaccurate coordinates so a straight polyline is being drawn on a map. Can you help me in this case?

Comment: @shanmkha You might want to check if polyline generated is correct though this utility https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility
just pust the encodeply line in the field and click decodeplyline, it should mark the waypoints on the map. If its wrong you can try appending it in the url `&sensor=false&waypoints=optimize:true&mode=driving`

Comment: @SahdeepSingh I checked through utility but the problem is some coordinates in the are missing so I am getting straight polyline at the middle of the route. Can I provide my encodeply and my location so you can get an idea?