# Flutter - Polyline Not drawing line inside Available screen size

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart, polyline, google-polyline

How can I get polyline inside available screensize?

I'm using [Flutter Goolge Map Plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter) , [Google Map Polyline](https://pub.dev/packages/google_map_polyline) Plugin

[image: Polyline drawing outside screensize]

Comment: your `GoogleMap.polylines` property is populated incorrectly

Comment: @pskink what i need to do?

Comment: you need to fix it

Comment: @pskink polyline only have these properties width, visible,color,points,polylineid,consumeTapEvents, endCap, startCap, zIndex, onTap, patterns,jointType,geodesic. i don't know, what to do

Comment: so most likely `points` are broken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all polylines added are placed wrong. you can follow my answer to generate then correctlly : https://stackoverflow.com/a/58831792/7910735

And for your Question you should use `CameraUpdate.newLatLngBounds()` just after placing the polylines.

Somewhat similiar to this

```
void animateCameraForOD() {
    mapController.animateCamera(
      CameraUpdate.newLatLngBounds(
          LatLngBounds(
                southwest: LatLng(
                    fromLocationLatLng.latitude <= toLocationLatLng.latitude
                        ? fromLocationLatLng.latitude
                        : toLocationLatLng.latitude,
                    fromLocationLatLng.longitude <= toLocationLatLng.longitude
                        ? fromLocationLatLng.longitude
                        : toLocationLatLng.longitude),
                northeast: LatLng(
                    fromLocationLatLng.latitude <= toLocationLatLng.latitude
                        ? toLocationLatLng.latitude
                        : fromLocationLatLng.latitude,
                    fromLocationLatLng.longitude <= toLocationLatLng.longitude
                        ? toLocationLatLng.longitude
                        : fromLocationLatLng.longitude)),100),
    );
  }
```

It will make your both LatLngs to be zoomed out to be in the given bounds with padding also.